# How to use a different texture on intersecting part of 2 quads

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change a part of a Quad that has a SpriteRenderer attached to it. Let's say I have a red Quad and a blue Quad, and then I drag one onto the other (fast or slow), the intersecting part should be colored using a green sprite. This illustration shows the scenario I'm trying to solve.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

First, if your mid color will be the correct mixture of other two color, in this case it would be yellow, you can use Mobile Particle/Additive or Mobile Particle/Multiply Shaders.

In a second way, you can write your own shader that takes the intersection area as parameter and paint your textures according to parameters.